# Selecting date ranges in hive db?

Tags: sql, hive

I have a transactions table in Hive.
Goal: count number of distinct transactions from maximum date to 3 months earlier: max(date) - 3M.

My date field is a variant of timestamp: 2017-09-30 23:59:00.0

Here is what I have done so far:

```
select count(distinct(transaction_id)) from table
where max(cast(date_fld_ts as date)) - INTERVAL '3' MONTH
```

It fails to run, please advise what do I miss here?

ERROR:

```
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
select count(distinct(transaction_id)) from db.table 
where max(cast(date_fld_ts as date)) - INTERVAL '3' MONTH

Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10128]: Line 2:6 Not yet supported place for UDAF 'max' [SQL State=42000, DB Errorcode=10128]
1 statement failed.

Execution time: 0.48s
```

Comment: Not familiar with Hive, but you should probably change `where` to `having`

Comment: @HoneyBadger changed to having, got an error:
`Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException HAVING specified without GROUP BY [SQL State=42000, DB Errorcode=40000]
1 statement failed.
`

Comment: @steves with `having` you have to put `group by column`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an aggregate function in `where`. Instead get the `max` date and use it later.

```
select count(distinct transaction_id)
from (select max(cast(date_fld_ts as date)) over() as max_date,t.*
      from table t
     ) t
where date_fld_ts >= add_months(max_date,-3) and date_fld_ts <= max_date
```

Comment: @vamsi_prabhala I am running it now...it's almost 6min and it didn't finish yet. 
Why this solution is faster?:
`select count(distinct(transaction_id)) from mddb.mddb 
where date_fld_ts <= '2017-09-30 23:59:00.0' and date_fld_ts >= '2017-06-30 23:59:00.0'`